# Racket - Check-expect: expects 2 arguments, but found only 1

Tags: racket

How do I get around this problem, I've been at it for a while.
It keeps giving me this error: 
**check-expect: expects 2 arguments, but found only 1**

Its not counting the list as one argument by itself, I think that is the error, but how would I go about fixing this? I've tried doing (count-in cell (list cells)) but it then gives me an error saying **define: expected a variable, but found a part**

**Definitions**

```
(define-struct Cell (x y)

(define (count-in cell cells)
(cond [(member? cell cells) 1]
  [else 0]))
```

**Check-expect, here is where the error comes in**

```
(check-expect (count-in (make-Cell 100 123) 
(list 
(make-Cell 104 123) (make-Cell 45 67)) 
(cond [(member? (make-Cell 100 123)
(list 
(make-Cell 104 123) (make-Cell 45 67)))1] 
  [else 0])1)
```

Comment: copy-paste error, this one says `check-expect: expects 2 arguments, but found only 1`.

Comment: yes, sorry it was probably the other errors from me messing around with it. Fixed it thank you, but I still don't know how to get around this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed it"? The error is different now but not the one you say. How can we help you if you don't post the code that gives you the problem you describe?

Comment: Fixed the copy-paste error. This is the code I am using, and it is producing a check-expect error.   check-expect: expects 2 arguments, but found only 1. This code does produce this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This passes your test

```scm
(define-struct Cell (x y))

(define (count-in cell cells)
  (cond
    [(member? cell cells) 1]
    [else 0]))

(check-expect
 (count-in (make-Cell 100 123)
           (list (make-Cell 104 123)
                 (make-Cell 45 67)))
 (cond
   [(member? (make-Cell 100 123) (list (make-Cell 104 123) (make-Cell 45 67))) 1] 
   [else 0]))
```

You should really learn how to indent Scheme code, and use the DrRacket's indentation feature and parenthesis coloring.

Comment: Wow, my error was caused by 1 simple bracket, I did not include                        (list (make-Cell 104 123)
        (make-Cell 45 67))     within my count-in code, thank you very much for the patience and help.